# Azure Table Take(N) method in Python

Tags: python, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to fetch given number of rows from Azure Storage Table.
I can find Java example in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/03/05/windows-azure-storage-client-for-java-tables-deep-dive.aspx) and .Net example in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803362.aspx), both of them use `Take` method.

But, how about Python? is it missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python supports it using ‘top’ instead of ‘take’. You should be able to do something like below:

table_service.query_entities('tasktable', "PartitionKey eq 'tasksSeattle'", 'description', ‘8’)   // To get 8 rows.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Table Storage has a new python library in preview release that is available for installation via pip. To install use the following pip command

```
pip install azure-data-tables
```

Instead of top, there is the `results_per_page` keyword argument for list and query entities. For example,

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
table_client = TableClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, "myTableName")
for entity in table_client.list_entities(results_per_page=8):
    print(entity)
```

For more samples on querying and listing entities, check out the samples in the azure-sdk-for-python repository [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples).

(FYI, I am a Microsoft employee on the Azure SDK for Python team)